# Jquery Modal Dialog with blankout screen

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am loading a Jquery modal popup as follows :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#tn_select').load('MyPopup.aspx');
});


</script>
```

and the css is as follows :-

```
.modal_block
{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.modal_part
{
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
}

.modal_dialog
{
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
   left: 25%;
   padding: 1%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 0;
   background: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

How can I make the other part of the screen (background) greyed out and the user cannot click on anything other than this modal dialog?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's  http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

```
$(".modal_part").dialog({ 
     modal: true   //pass this while initializing dialog
});
```

Comment: ah ok I will check my css then.  Is there a way to avoid the close button at the top of the panel?

Comment: There are some ways.We cannot do it in options.Those are hacks.Check here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-hide-the-close-button-in-a-jquery-mobile-dialog

Comment: in firebug i found this <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="left: 798px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="tn_select" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">.  You have no idea how I can edit that right?  Do not wish to touch the actual jquery css